# Running api on different servers

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, routes

I am currently running an express server. It is having routes which is computational and memory extensive. I want to shift that api routes to different server so that it does not harm any other apis.

I am currently proxy passing that request using nginx. But I want to do it in express level in order to get more control.

Is there any different approach or any other npm package to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a solution like [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware). Intregation is super-simple too.